# How to manage composer dependencies for a package

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I am using Symfony and developing an independent reusable bundle, I want to install this package in symfony app.

Here is my composer.json look like in reusable bundle

```
{
    ...
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.1",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "2.2.0",
        "knplabs/doctrine-behaviors": "2.0.8"
    }
}
```

Here is my composer.json for Symfony app

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.1",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/console": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "6.1.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/package-versions-deprecated": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        },
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php81": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "6.1.*"
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to install my reusable bundle, it always gives me this error

```
  Problem 1
    - knplabs/doctrine-behaviors v2.0.8 requires symfony/cache ^4.4|^5.1 -> found symfony/cache[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.48, v5.1.0, ..., v5.4.15] but the package is fixed to v6.1.7 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - oromedialab/corebundle 0.0.1 requires knplabs/doctrine-behaviors 2.0.8 -> satisfiable by knplabs/doctrine-behaviors[v2.0.8].
    - Root composer.json requires oromedialab/corebundle ^0.0.1 -> satisfiable by oromedialab/corebundle[0.0.1].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require oromedialab/corebundle:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require oromedialab/corebundle:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Why is the conflict happening here?

Thanks

Comment: How do you install that bundle? Sounds like you already use some of the required packages in different versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't set specific dependencies versions in reusable package because it can cause some conflicts. Add `^` to version declarations.

```
{
    ...
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.1",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "^2.2.0",
        "knplabs/doctrine-behaviors": "^2.0.8"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, okay, reasoning is clear to me, but why does `^` help here? And what is it for? Is this specific to Symfony Bundles or Composer Packages, or both?

Comment: @hakre it allows composer to install updated version of package https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#caret-version-range- here is more specific explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Yes, I _know_ what it does, the reason I raised that question was in context of your answer: Why does the `^` solves it for the question asked? So why not add that not as a comment but edit it into the answer? (I could do that now with your reasoning, but I think it should be "your" edit). Let me know if that bothers you.